# Simulate pushbutton Clicked

Tags: qt

I write code in QT to detect mouse clicks in server and simulate them in client side. I can detect click on buttons as left click and in client, it clicks on position of button but client doesn't realize it as a push button click and related slot doesn't run. 
In client it is realized as a left click and mouseReleaseEvent function being ran. how code can detect it as a pushbutton click?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Qt UI testing:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html It helpful for generate keyboard and mouse events.

```
QWidget widget;
QTest::mouseClick(&widget, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, QPoint(clicked,point));
```

Comment: I generate mouse click using mouseClick function but QTest doesn't emit signal. It doesn't run the SLOT related to pushbutton!